# how to remove shortcut file in visual source safe 2005

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

How to Remove in following shortcut symbol in visual source safe file
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'Branch files': [image]

P.S.: I hope you understand, what this shortcut symbol means and how behavior changed after branching. If not, better read something about this topic: e.g.: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y90e01b4(v=vs.80).aspx